# python 2.7: TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to start **RIDE** (Standalone RobotFramework Test Data Editor) using `ride.py` after installing all pre-requisites, by following all the steps mentioned [here](http://www.swtestacademy.com/getting-started-robotframework/)

section `Installing RIDE (Standalone RobotFramework Test Data Editor)` in the above link, 3 steps are finished successfully. In the 4th step, got the error.

in **cmd** (4th step),

```
C:\Users\naveen>ride.py
```

But getting the following exception:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Following is the environment:

```
 1. Windows 8 OS
 2. Python 2.7.13 - 64 bit
 3. robotframework  -2.9.2
 4. wxPython - 2.8.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **compatibility** issue.

Just installed all **32-bit** versions (Python, wxPython etc.) and it worked for me.